# Logging errors in GCloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud

I'm writing a project using Python hosted on a local Django server.

This same project is also deployed to GCloud where it's hosted on Google's Cloud server. But every time it has any issues post-deployment, the GCloud's logging is always a hassle, mainly because it's very uninformative.

When I run my project on my local machine, using the 'runserver' command in the command prompt, any time an issue pops up, I'm able to view it through the command prompt (eg. `django.db.utils.IntegrityError at line abc, method xyz`).

Is there anything on GCloud that can give me logging akin to that? Especially if its an issue that has happened awhile back? Preferably something that is within the free trial, if possible?

The best thing I could find was the Log Viewer on the project dashboard and the details it gives me is pretty scarce, something along these lines:

```
error: 500
source: /app/submit/
resource.type="gae_app"
resource.labels.module_id="default"
resource.labels.version_id="20201117t191425"
logName=(...)
jsonPayload.trace="5ec93d7a13aac6b28fe5a8134db1691b"
```

It does not actually explain what causes the Error 500, as well as the details of the error.

And the documentation itself can sometimes have a bit too much self-promoting and a lot of links to broad topics that don't always give me what I can use.

Comment: I didn't catch how do you log your errors. Can you also  share the service that you use? You tagged app engine, is that correct? if so, can you share your app.yaml file also?

Comment: I am not sure if I used the right tags but its basically the Google Cloud Platform: https://console.cloud.google.com/ . In the Navigation Menu, there's an option called "Legacy Log Viewer", which is how Google Cloud log errors. This is what I use. I asking for alternative ways to read this log, because the data in the Log Viewer is not detailed enough.

Comment: The Cloud Logging console show you the full version of logs. You haven't additional information elsewhere. But, if you lack of information, it's maybe because  your error trace has not been caught on the service that you use. So what, I asked you on which service you host your piece of code that trigger the error.

Comment: I am not sure, as Im not the one responsible for the deployment(it is a group effort), so I dont have access to the app.yaml, but it should be under the GAE

Comment: It's difficult to help like this! GAE is a wide platform, with standard and flex environment, 1st and 2nd generation. Quite difficult without a reproductible piece of code and more details...

Comment: I agree with the comments above that it's difficult to reproduce the issue you are facing with the information you currently shared. What I would advise you to do at this point is checking the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs) on how to write and view logs for app engine

Comment: I've went and check with the one responsible for the app.yaml. As far as I can tell, there's no service included. Only things of note is using flex environment, as well as gunicorn.